# Understanding Hyperledger Fabric Setting

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am new to blockchain and just have the basic understanding in the Bitcoin PoW scheme.

After reading the key concepts of Hyperledger Fabric https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en//latest/key_concepts.html, I have some difficulties in understanding the setting.

In the **Membership section** [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en//latest/membership/membership.html#msp-structure), it said ***"KeyStore for Private Key:*** This folder is defined for the local MSP of a peer or orderer node." But Organization can have multiple Peer nodes. So which nodes are responsible of the private key then? My understanding is that private should be stored at one place only.

For the whole **Peer section** (see [this link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en//latest/peers/peers.html)), it seems to suggest that the Peer nodes only validate the endorsed transactions according to the endorsement policy. What about the consensus algorithms? (e.g. something like PoW, PoS, PoET)

I know that Fabric implements *Kafka* (see [Hyperledger Architecture, Volume 1](https://www.hyperledger.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Hyperledger_Arch_WG_Paper_1_Consensus.pdf)). But then, I also find out the paper in arXiv that further confuses me [A Byzantine Fault-Tolerant Ordering Service for the Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain Platform](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06921v1). This paper seems to suggest that the orderer nodes are also involved in Byzantine Fault Tolerance (BFT). However, my understanding of orderer nodes is that they are only responsible for ordering the endorsed transactions and broadcast them to all the peer nodes (see [this link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en//latest/peers/peers.html#phase-2-packaging)).

Now, I am confused how the Hyperledger Fabric network verifies the endorsed transactions. What is the default consensus algorithm and how does it fit into the picture of the **Peer section** as described from the official website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So which nodes are responsible of the private key then? My
>   understanding is that private should be stored at one place only.

Each node has its own private key, stored securely in its own file system, or on a hardware device accessible only to it.

> it seems to suggest that the Peer nodes only validate the endorsed
>   transactions according to the endorsement policy. What about the
>   consensus algorithms? (e.g. something like PoW, PoS, PoET)

The consensus is done on the order of the transactions and not on their content.
The endorsement policy, dictates whether a transaction is seen as valid or not by the network.

> This paper seems to suggest that the orderer nodes are also involved
>   in Byzantine Fault Tolerance (BFT). However, my understanding of
>   orderer nodes is that they are only responsible for ordering the
>   endorsed transactions and broadcast them to all the peer nodes

Right, that's correct - The current Fabric implementation has no BFT orderer. However, the consensus is pluggable and in case you implement your own orderer, you can just switch the Kafka based one with a BFT one.

> Now, I am confused how the Hyperledger Fabric network verifies the
>   endorsed transactions. What is the default consensus algorithm and how
>   does it fit into the picture of the Peer section as described from the
>   official website?

It verifies them via 2 ways:

- Endorsement policy - each transaction has a target to one or more chaincodes (namespaces in the DB). Each such namespace has an chaincode has its own endorsement policy. If the transaction is signed by peers such that the endorsement policy is satisifed, then the transaction is deemed as one that passed the endorsement policy.
- MVCC(Multi version concurrency control) - A transaction that read keys during its execution, records their versions, and then upon commit the peer checks that the versions didn't change, so the causality of the data still remains intact.

Comment: I still have some difficulties in understanding the relation between Kafka (or BFT) and Orderers. Is Kafka just a platform for orderers to perform fast communication to all peer nodes? or it also consists of consensus algorithm like BFT?

Comment: Kafka presents the ordering service nodes an abstraction of a shared queue, which is used to order the transactions. 
It is not byzantine tolerant.

Comment: It seems that the verification process is just traditional checking of digital signature and other policy checking. So, is it safe to just use SOLO or Kafka without consensus (e.g. BFT, PoW,...etc)? Is it because Fabric is a permissioned blockchain, so there is some trade-off here?

Comment: If you use a CFT (crash fault tolerant) orderer and not a BFT orderer, then if it is hijacked/hacked - it can send different blocks to different peers and fork your network.
However it cannot forge a transaction of a user or a peer signature.